# Xampp Virtual Host for sub directory

Tags: php, apache, xampp, virtualhost, httpd.conf

### Question

I would like to map

```
www.mydomain.com/some/url
```

to

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/some/dir
```

### What I've got

- Xampp
- Wordpress

**htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /some/path/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /some/path/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Hosts file**

```
127.0.0.1 www.mydomain.com
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf** (included in `httpd.conf`)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/someDir/"
    ServerName mydomain.com/some/path
</VirtualHost>
```

**additional info (httpd.conf)**

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

### Current Outcome

500 Internal Server Error error log shows

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
```

Comment: `ServerName mydomain.com/some/path` must be `ServerName mydomain.com` instead. And you should add `ServerAlias www.mydomain.com` maybe.

Comment: What is `Require all granted` meant to be?

Comment: And, most important: _what is your question here?_

Comment: `Require all granted` is the default setting from xampp for the directory directive (for the document Root, afaik). I am cought a bit offguard here, but I think it maximizes access. If the additional httpd.conf settings are not of relevance for the questions, I'll remove them, to clean up my request. My Question is: Are these settings everything, which is needed to get the desired result, which I thought they weren't and if they aren't: "What am I missing?"

Comment: You are missing the most vital detail inside your description: what is the issue? What does not work? What happens if you request the domain? What do the log files show? What does the browser show?

Comment: I thought I could keep it more general. Ok, sry. I've added some info. I've also made your suggested changes in the vhosts.conf. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: The error indicates that there are redirection rules somewhere, could that be the case? Maybe for some non-www to www redirection or vice versa?

Comment: I am running a wordpress system and just added its `htaccess` to the question. As I've stated above, I thought my questions was more general and I didn't want to provide to many irrelevant details. If anything is not of importance, please let me know and I'll remove it and even more so, if any useful information still is missing. Many thanks for your support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the alias to your **httpd.conf**

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /some/url C:/xampp/htdocs/some/dir
```